# Is "develop" transitive in "technology developed by X"?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

In the following phrase, is *developed* a transitive verb?

> Technology developed by the XXX company.

Comment: *Developed* is the *past participle* of the verb *develop* employed as a *passive participle*: it means *Technology which was developed by XXX*, which represents a passive form of *XXX developed [this] technology*. So, yes, *develop* here is a transitive verb.

Comment: Why did you have a doubt? Where have you checked so far?

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/develop

Comment: @StoneyB Huh? (I thought) I was very clear till I read the comment. Surely, it needs to have a disclaimer first. :)

Comment: Once again there's a confusing use of a technical term outside its proper environs. _Transitivity_ is a property of clauses, not verbs; practically any verb can be used transitively or intransitively, given the right construction. And this particular noun phrase has been tampered with by Passive, so that it no longer has a direct object. Since one definition of _transitive_ is 'has a direct object', passive clauses are by that definition always intransitive, except for the cases where an indirect object has been promoted to d.o. and thence to subject, like _She was given the key to the city._

Comment: rachel, questions are expected to show considerable evidence of research and be of interest to language experts (professionals and enthusiastic amateurs). However you might be interested in our new proposal specifically tailored for those who want to learn the English language: English Language Learners (ell.stackexchange.com). On EL&U this kind of questions are considered at best too basic and this might explain the reason why you don't have got an answer yet, but on ELL they are welcome. Please, take a look now or, at any rate, be aware that that proposal exists. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnLawler: To most people, verbs can be transitive; the criterion you mention 'has a direct object' is what people normally use. In this system, a clause is not really said to be transitive, nor a specific instance of a verb, but only a certain predicate frame of a verb. This is the way Stoney uses the term too.

Comment: So, in this "predicate frame", is it a transitive verb or not? Passives don't have direct objects; they have subjects instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [web definition](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=define%20transitive%20verb&oq=define%20transitive%20verb&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j62l3.4901j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for **transitive verb**:

> transitive verb
>   a verb (or verb construction) that requires an object in order to be grammatical

In this case, 'developed' is the verb, the object of which is 'technology'. For easier analysis (as pointed out by [StoneyB](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/24489/stoneyb)), the sentence could be rearranged as follows:

> The XXX company developed this technology.

This points out the following:

- Subject — "The XXX company"
- Verb — "developed"
- Object — "this technology"

The sentence could not use this verb without the object without the meaning being changed/lost.

Thus, **in this context**, 'developed' is a **transitive verb**.